# Erro Target Unreachable, identifier 'ClienteBean' resolved to null

Tags: java, jsf, hibernate, jpa, ejb

Sistema com erro:

**Mensagem de Erro:**

> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /index.xhtml @22,72
>   value="#{ClienteBean.cliente.nome}": Target Unreachable, identifier
>   'ClienteBean' resolved to null    at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:95)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1045)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
>     at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1258)
>     at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
>     ... 24 more Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target
>   Unreachable, identifier 'ClienteBean' resolved to null    at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:74)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:58)   at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:168)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
>     ... 35 more

**Controller Bean**

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controller;

/**
 *
 * @author alunoti
 */
import dao.ClienteDAO;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;
import modelo.Cliente;

/**
 *
 * @author andii
 */
@Named(value = "ClienteBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ClienteBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private ClienteDAO clienteDAO;
    private Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    private List<Cliente> clientes;

    public void novo(){
        cliente = new Cliente();
    }

    public void gravar() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        boolean resultado = clienteDAO.gravar(cliente);

        if (resultado) {
            cliente = new Cliente();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Cliente gravado com sucesso"));
        } else {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Falha ao gravar cliente!"));
        }
    }

    public void selecionar(ActionEvent evento) {
        Long codigo = (Long) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("codigo");
        cliente = clienteDAO.selecionar(codigo);
    }

    public void remover() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        boolean resultado = clienteDAO.remover(cliente);

        if (resultado) {
            cliente = new Cliente();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Cliente removido com sucesso"));
        } else {
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Falha ao remover cliente!"));
        }
    }

    //Getters e Setters
    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public List<Cliente> getClientes() {
        clientes = clienteDAO.listar();
        return clientes;
    }

    public void setClientes(List<Cliente> clientes) {
        this.clientes = clientes;
    }
}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns   ="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h ="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f ="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="dadosCliente">
            <fieldset style="width: 350px">
                <legend>Novo cliente</legend>
                <h:commandButton value="Novo" action="#{ClienteBean.novo}" />
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset style="width: 350px">
                <legend>Dados do cliente</legend>
                <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                    <h:outputText value="Nome" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{ClienteBean.cliente.nome}" />
                    <h:commandButton value="Gravar" action="#{ClienteBean.gravar}" />
                    <h:commandButton value="Remover" action="#{ClienteBean.remover}" rendered="#{ClienteBean.cliente.codigo > 0}" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </fieldset>
        </h:form>

        <h:form>
            <fieldset style="width: 350px">
                <legend>Clientes</legend>
                <h:dataTable value="#{ClienteBean.clientes}" var="cliente" border="1">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="CODIGO" /></f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{Cliente.codigo}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header"><h:outputText value="NOME" /></f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{Cliente.nome}" />
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <h:commandButton value="Selecionar" actionListener="#{ClienteBean.selecionar}">
                            <f:attribute name="codigo" value="#{Cliente.codigo}" />
                            <f:ajax render=":dadosCliente" execute="@this" />
                        </h:commandButton>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </fieldset>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="crudPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>modelo.Cliente</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/bancoteste?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Tela do Sistema**
[image: Tela do sistema]

**Tela do sistema com erro:**
[image: bug sistema]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive um problema semelhante. Não sei se é o caso em questão, mas ao usar o netbeans e criar os managedBeans ele importa de:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
```

Se for usar o GlassFish não tem problema, pois ele já tem o Weld embutido, mas no caso do tomcat é melhor mudar as importações para:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
```

Ou acrescentar as dependências do Weld caso for trabalhar com injeção de Dependências:

```
        <!--Weld (implementação do CDI)--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.10.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Weld depende do Jandex--> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Faça o XHTML referenciar apenas `clienteBean` e não `ClienteBean`
2. Remova a anotação `@Named`
3. Insira a anotação `@ManagedBean`
4. Altere o escopo de `@SessionScoped` para `@ViewScoped`

Comment: Devo alter no ClienteBean.java: SessionScoped paraViewScoped ??

Comment: @alexjosesilva isso vai funcionar. Mas talvez não seja o que você quer. Se você quiser manter o `@SessionScoped` você deve abrir uma sessão HTTP antes tentar acessar a página em questão

Comment: não resolveu.. ainda esta saindo o mesmo erro!

Comment: afinal que erro é esse: Target Unreachable, identifier 'ClienteBean' resolved to null ?

Comment: @alexjosesilva ah cara, agora que vi. No XHTML você deve referenciar o seu ManagedBean com a primeira letra com letra minúscula. Assim: `value="#{clienteBean.cliente.nome}` e não `value="#{ClienteBean.cliente.nome}`

Comment: @alexjosesilva é o `NullPointerException` do JSF.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66350/discussion-between-igor-venturelli-and-alexjosesilva).